# Alamofire parameters based on value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm posting parameters to my API with Alamofire. 
I'm trying to use different parameters based on if we have a password or not. 
See a part of my code below:

```
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [:]

    if (password != nil) {
        let parameters: [String : Any] = [
            "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
            "firstName": firstName,
            "lastName": lastName,
            "password": password ?? "",
            "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
            "location": location?.json ?? [:],
            "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
            "gender": gender.rawValue,
            "avatarId": 1,
            "email": email,
            "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
        ]
    } else {
        let parameters: [String : Any] = [
            "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
            "firstName": firstName,
            "lastName": lastName,
            "password": password ?? "",
            "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
            "location": location?.json ?? [:],
            "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
            "gender": gender.rawValue,
            "avatarId": 1,
            "email": email,
            "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
        ]
    }

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [
```

when I set a breakpoint behind the if/else statement it says there are 0 elements. 
 What am I doing wrong? 
 I can probably also speed this up as it takes longer to build this way.

Comment: remove let in your if statements. Edit: Nirav D is faster than me :)

Comment: @Ludovic Tried doing so but this gives other errors. http://imgur.com/a/yqUsE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `if-else` block you are creating new constant `parameters`, so change your code like this.

```
let parameters: [String: Any]

if (password != nil) {
    parameters = [
        "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "password": password ?? "",
        "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
        "location": location?.json ?? [:],
        "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
        "gender": gender.rawValue,
        "avatarId": 1,
        "email": email,
        "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
    ] as [String : Any]
} else {
    parameters = [
        "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "password": password ?? "",
        "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
        "location": location?.json ?? [:],
        "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
        "gender": gender.rawValue,
        "avatarId": 1,
        "email": email,
        "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
    ] as [String : Any]
}
```

Comment: Already tried doing so but this gives me some other errors.
http://imgur.com/a/yqUsE

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo Try to replace your code with my one and put as [String:Any] at last.

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo Also this error doesn't related with the dictionary.

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo Check my answer I have written with `as [String:Any]` at last not with the parameters declaration, Replace whole your code with my one.

Comment: Just replaced it with your code. It now takes like 2 minutes to build and then it stops as it's to complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135086/discussion-between-matthijs-otterloo-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring your parameters variable rather then assigning to it.

You can only assign to a let variable a single time, however that assignment does not have to occur as part of the same statement as the declaration.

For example:

```
let parameters: [String: Any]

if (password != nil) {
    parameters = [
        "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "password": password ?? "",
        "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
        "location": location?.json ?? [:],
        "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
        "gender": gender.rawValue,
        "avatarId": 1,
        "email": email,
        "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
    ]
} else {
    parameters = [
        "displayName": firstName + " " + lastName,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "password": password ?? "",
        "passwordConfirmation": password ?? "",
        "location": location?.json ?? [:],
        "wallet": wallet?.json ?? [:],
        "gender": gender.rawValue,
        "avatarId": 1,
        "email": email,
        "authExternalAccessToken": accessToken ?? "",
    ]
}

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [
```

Comment: Some comment as on the post below, this gives me other errors.
http://imgur.com/a/yqUsE

Comment: @NiravD Yes, that's likely the problem. But how can I solve this? Because removing the let statement  isn't fixing it.